# How to provide apollo client configuration with dagger hilt?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-client, dagger-hilt

I am going to create a multi-module app with two modules (home and graphql). I want to set the apollo configuration with the dagger hilt. But when I provide the apollo client in the graphql module with the hilt and then inject it into the ViewModel of the home module

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val api: ApolloApi
) :
    ViewModel()
```

**I get this hilt error**:

```
/home/mehdi/StudioProjects/client_app/app/build/generated/source/kapt/developmentDebug/com/mykuyaclient/MykuyaClientApplication_HiltComponents.java:145: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.apollo.ApolloApi cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MykuyaClientApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.example.apollo.ApolloApi is injected at
          com.mykuyaclient.home.presentation.main.viewmodel.HomeViewModel(…, api)
      com.mykuyaclient.home.presentation.main.viewmodel.HomeViewModel is injected at
          com.mykuyaclient.home.presentation.main.viewmodel.HomeViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.mykuyaclient.MykuyaClientApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.mykuyaclient.MykuyaClientApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.mykuyaclient.MykuyaClientApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

**This is my hilt module object**:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApolloModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApi() = ApolloApi()
    
}
```

**and this is my apollo api class**:

```
class ApolloApi {

    fun getApolloClient(): ApolloClient {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
        return ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
}
```